# Is there any way to use multilanguage in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

i need to implement multilanguage in a ReactJS webpage, but i was able to found only using native and redux. How can i implement this function in a reactjs app?

Comment: What do you mean by `multilanguage`?  Do you mean internationalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are are mean by different technology, then yes you can use that by creating 
**MICRO SERVICES**

**microservice** can be written using a different technology. This simplifies the selection of the most appropriate tech stack for the specific needs of your service. The microservice architecture allows decoupled services written in different programming languages to peacefully coexist with other fragments. This is also good news if you’re looking to scale your solution in the future. With microservices, you can add new components to the system painlessly or scale services separately from one another.

https://skelia.com/articles/5-major-benefits-microservice-architecture/